# Pynetdicom3 transfer syntax

Tags: python-3.x, dicom

I am trying to make a c-STORE via pynetdicom3, but everytime this shows up

ValueError: No Accepted Presentation Context for 'dataset'

I've searched inside the pynetdicom3 code and it compare the SOPclassUID of the dcm to a bunch of transfer syntax, no one is the same as the SOPclassUID, leaving the syntax as None.

How can i solve this?
What is the SOPclassUID and what does it have to do with the syntax?

Code:

```
ae = AE(config.get('move', 'aet'), port=pynetport, scu_sop_class=QueryRetrieveSOPClassList) 
assocstore = ae.associate(configworkstationaddress, int(configworkstationport))
*stuff*
dsstore = dcmread(dcmfilenames[0])
status = assocstore.send_c_store(dsstore)
print(status)
assocstore.release()
```

Comment: Please add your source code to the question, so that we see what you are doing. Right now it's quite difficult to help you.

Comment: i'll edit the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that you are trying to send DICOM file to another DICOM application. That means your application has to act as SCU (Service Class User, DICOM term for client) of the relevant Storage SOP class. Currently your AE intialisation is declaring `scu_sop_class=QueryRetrieveSOPClassList`, which means that your application tells to the other side, that "I want to make queries to you and nothing else". Since you actually want to send a DICOM object over the network, you should declare the relevant capabilities instead.

All in all, first try to set up your AE with storage capabilites and see what happens:

```
ae = AE(config.get('move', 'aet'), port=pynetport, scu_sop_class=StorageSOPClassList)
```

Comment: You are right. Just changed that and worked perfectly. Just a question, StoreSOPClassList works with C-FIND request ?

Comment: Probably not. To enable both functionalities at the same time, you have to combine the two SOP class lists into one single list and give this as the `scu_sop_class` argument.

Comment: So in case i want to do both i should use two different AE, right?

Comment: No, not necessarily. You have to add all the relevant SOP class objects to your AE that you need. The `StorageSOPClassList` and `QueryRetrieveSOPClassList` are just premade lists of commonly used SOP classes. If you need both in one application, just combine these two lists into one big list. Or you can also pick and choose individual classes from these lists, if needed.

Comment: How can i do this? 

ae = AE(config.get('move', 'aet'), port=pynetport, scu_sop_class=[QueryRetrieveSOPClassList,StorageSOPClassList]) ?

Comment: That's out of scope for this question, this is basic Python skills. Search stackoverflow or google how to join two lists in Python. :)